# Extracting key value pairs from JSON into a TXT file via Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to JSON so don't have much idea how it can be done.
I'm trying to extract KEYs and VALUEs from a nested JSON file. The JSON downloaded from a firebase app.
The sample file is like

```
{
  "Raspberry" : {
    "Front" : {
      "07-05-2021 21:56" : [ {
        "ID" : "174031",
        "LAT" : "17.0015",
        "LONG" : "08.4445"
      },
{
        "ID" : "174032",
        "LAT" : "17.0015",
        "LONG" : "08.4445"
      }
}
```

The output I'm expecting in a TXT is

```
Raspberry
------------------
Front
------------------
ID = 174031
LAT = 17.0015
LONG = 08.4445
==================
ID = 174032
LAT = 17.0015
LONG = 08.4445
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share what attempts you've made at solving this, and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON text is not correctly formatted, is it possible there is additional data at the end that you're missing? For example, there is no closing ']' and there are two less closing '}' than required to make it correct.

You can use the `json` module to load your json if it would be formatted correctly as follow:

```
with open('JSONFILENAME.json') as file:
    your_dictionary = json.load(file)
```

`your_dictionary` then becomes a standard Python dictionary with the correct keys and values.

Comment: I'm sorry, the file was too large hence I've just copied the first two keys. But yes, the json is correctly formatted. I'm just looking for ways to get the data into a text file as in mentioned format

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it. Here's the code.

input.json (input)

```
{
  "Raspberry": [
    {
      "City": "New York City",
      "Country": "US",
      "State": "New York"
    },
    {
      "ID": "174031",
      "LAT": "17.0015",
      "LONG": "08.4445"
    },
    {
      "ID": "174032",
      "LAT": "17.0015",
      "LONG": "08.4445"
    }
  ]
}
```

main.py

```
import json

person_dict = {}
final_dict = ""


#import json file and load the content in person_dict as a dictionary
with open('input.json') as f:
    person_dict.update(json.load(f))
    #get the first list from the json(person_dict)
    first = list(person_dict['Raspberry'])
    for data in first:
        try:
            final_dict = final_dict + ("Country: " + data[str('Country')] + "\n")
            final_dict = final_dict + ("State: " + data[str('State')] + "\n")
            final_dict = final_dict + ("City: " + data[str('City')] + "\n")
            final_dict = final_dict + ("====================================" + "\n")
        except:
            pass
        try:
            final_dict = final_dict + ("Id: " + data[str('ID')] + "\n")
            final_dict = final_dict + ("Latitude: " + data[str('LAT')] + "\n")
            final_dict = final_dict + ("Longitude: " + data[str('LONG')] + "\n")
            final_dict = final_dict + ("------------------------------------" + "\n")
        except:
            pass

text_file = open("sample.txt", "w") # write output as a txt
n = text_file.write(final_dict)
text_file.close()
```

sample.txt (output)

```
Country: US
State: New York
City: New York City
====================================
Id: 174031
Latitude: 17.0015
Longitude: 08.4445
------------------------------------
Id: 174032
Latitude: 17.0015
Longitude: 08.4445
------------------------------------
```